# Lowest Big-O of 3^n^3

Tags: asymptotics

Figuring out the lowest Big-O for $\ 7n^2$ for example,  is straight-forward by finding witnesses C and k such as $\ n > 7 $ therefore $\ 7n^2 < n^3  $ so k = 7 and C = 1. So $\ 7n^2 $ has Big-O($\ n^3$)

But, how do I find the lowest Big-O for something like $\ 3^{n^3}$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your example.  The lowest big-O of $7n^2$ is $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed. It's also included in n^3 subset. It was a bad example considering my question of having the lowest Big-O possible. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see much that you can do with $3^{n^3}$.
However, you can write it as
$e^{\ln(3) n^3}$,
and this could be written as
$e^{O(n^3)}$.
It could also be written as
$e^{n^{O(1)}}$,
but this almost seems an abuse of big-O notation, 
since so much information is lost
at each step.